# How do I override the main template in Plone 3?

Tags: plone, zope, plone-3.x

I'm working on a theme product for Plone 3.2.3. My theme product works perfectly on the default Plone installation. However, when I apply it to our existing site all the features of my theme are applied except the modifications to the main template.

The product file structure is based on the paster plone3_theme template and the files I've modified are as follows:

```
my.theme/
  my/
    theme/
      browser/
        configure.zcml
        templates/
          site_actions.pt
          ...
        viewlets.py
        viewletmanagers.py
      profiles/
        default/
          viewlets.xml
      skins/
        my_theme_custom_templates/
          main_template.pt
```

All of the changes I made in the `browser/` and `profiles/` directories are applied (including custom templates), but the custom main template is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure, that the `my_theme_custom_templates` folder is loaded before the `plone_templates` folder.

Go to http://localhost:8080/PLONE/portal_skins/manage_propertiesForm and check if your `my_theme_custom_templates` is on the second place in your active skin ("Skin selections"). Usually `custom` is on the first place, than you need to make sure your skin folders are directly underneath the `custom` folder or at least before `plone_templates`. Also check which skin is active in `Default skin`.

Comment: Thank you - that fixed it! There was also a stylesheet in the "custom" folder that was overriding the one belonging to my theme. I deleted it and now everything works as expected.